# Webpack bundling lodash throws syntax error

Tags: javascript, webpack, lodash

I am a newbie to module bundlers and following this video to learn how to use Webpack: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IG4UmULyoA

This is my incredibly simple package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "t1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"  
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.69.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  }
}
```

I installed lodash and imported its camelCase function as followed in my src/index.js:

```
import { camelCase } from 'lodash';
console.log(camelCase('hello world'));
```

I built it by `npm run build` and a bundled file in the dist/main.js is created, just like in the video that I linked above.

I embedded the bundled dist/main.js script into my index.html and it throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` in main.js line 2.

Tested in different browsers: Opera, Chrome and Edge but no difference and since bundled dist/main.js looks very complicated and minified, I can't understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: What does your webpack config look like (if any)?

Comment: I didn't create one, as the tutor in the video did not. I am following the video from scratch. Started at 3:18 in the video, you can see he doesn't have one either.

Comment: I managed to reproduce the issue but can't spot the problem due to Webpack's minification. If I build with `npx webpack --mode=development`, it's not minified but there's also no error

Comment: Oh my captain you're my hero! It worked on my local too. Since I am a newbie, a notice in the CLI was printing each time I built it as: "The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. And the tutor in the video was not getting that.
"

Comment: But even though the issue is solved, I don't understand what that option does and means.

Comment: See the doco for [Mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/#usage). I'd still be concerned about a syntax error in production mode

Comment: Ok, found it. It's an issue with the minified Lodash if you don't specify the page encoding. Add `<meta charset="utf-8">` to your HTML page. See https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4959

Comment: Confirmed. I beautified the dist/main.js in https://beautifier.io/. Overwritten the dist/main.js with the beautified version, reproduced the error, and the exception gets thrown on these lines:  
339: var Jt = Dt({
340: Ã€: "A", (THROWN HERE)

Comment: You should post these infos as an answer so that I can confirm it, you deserve the points, thank you so much. I will also edit my original post.